# Why does printing to stderr cause segmentation fault when dealing with ucontext?

Tags: c, posix, ucontext

I was working on a project for a course on Operating Systems. The task was to implement a library for dealing with threads, similar to `pthreads`, but much more simpler. The purpose of it is to practice scheduling algorithms. The final product is a `.a` file. The course is over and everything worked just fine (in terms of functionality).

Though, I got curious about an issue I faced. On three different functions of my source file, if I add the following line, for instance:

```
fprintf(stderr, "My lucky number is %d\n", 4);
```

I get a segmentation fault. The same doesn't happen if `stdout` is used instead, or if the formatting doesn't contain any variables.

That leaves me with two main questions:

1. Why does it only happen in three functions of my code, and not the others?
2. Could the creation of contexts using `getcontext()` and `makecontext()`, or the changing of contexts using `setcontext()` or `swapcontext()` mess up with the standard file descriptors?

My intuition says those functions could be responsible for that. Even more when given the fact that the three functions of my code in which this happens are functions that have contexts which other parts of the code switch to. Usually by `setcontext()`, though `swapcontext()` is used to go to the scheduler, for choosing another thread to execute.

Additionally, if that is the case, then:

3. What is the proper way to create threads using those functions?

I'm currently doing the following:

```
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Funct:  Creates an execution context for the function and arguments passed.
Input:  uc      -> Pointer where the context will be created.
        funct   -> Function to be executed in the context.
        arg     -> Argument to the function.
Return: If the function succeeds, 0 will be returned. Otherwise -1.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static int create_context(ucontext_t *uc, void *funct, void *arg)
{
    if(getcontext(uc) != 0) // Gets a context "model"
    {
        return -1;
    }
    stack_t *sp = (stack_t*)malloc(STACK_SIZE); // Stack area for the execution context
    if(!sp) // A stack area is mandatory
    {
        return -1;
    }
    uc->uc_stack.ss_sp = sp; // Sets stack pointer
    uc->uc_stack.ss_size = STACK_SIZE; // Sets stack size
    uc->uc_link = &context_end; // Sets the context to go after execution

    makecontext(uc, funct, 1, arg); // "Makes everything work" (can't fail)
    return 0;
}
```

This code is probably a little modified, but it is originally an online example on how to use u_context.

Comment: I would guess that you had some form of memory corruption or race condition; that's typically the cause when adding or removing a seemingly harmless line causes bugs.

Comment: No threads are executed simultaneously, so I guess race condition is off the table.
I have examined the executable with valgrind, but there were so many memory leaks that it's like finding a needle in a haystack. Though I don't think not freeing memory would cause this issue.

Comment: What is the value of `STACK_SIZE`?

Comment: `STACK_SIZE` is 8192 bytes.
Also, the `context_end` is created much like the same way.

Comment: @YuriJ: That might be insufficient for calling the `fprintf` function. What OS (and if Linux, what libc) are you using?

Comment: @YuriJ, try resolving those leaks. It is possible that you may find a bug!

Comment: I fixed all memory leaks. Valgrind outputs `All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible`. And... well, the bug is over. How cool is that? Thank you everyone for advice. Still I wonder what is the relation between these two things.

Should I leave the question open or close it? I'm kinda new here.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming glibc, the explanation is that `fprintf` with an unbuffered stream (such as `stderr` by default) internally creates an on-stack buffer which as a size of `BUFSIZE` bytes.  See the function `buffered_vfprintf` in `stdio-common/vfprintf.c`.  `BUFSIZ` is 8192, so you end up with a stack overflow because the stack you create is too small.

Comment: This is happening to me on arm-linux target (works well on x86-64 Linux), and changing stderr to stdout did stop the crash. Although I do not understand why would this happen since this is happening in only one instance of one function.